# Hyperas LSTM configuration assignment error

Tags: python, keras, hyperparameter-tuning

I have been working on my trivial keras lstm model trying to implement Hyperas with the following code that gives me an error I cannot resolve. I have just been experimenting around with Hyperas and it would be great to get this to work. My code in one file looks as follows:

```
from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.datasets import imdb
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from matplotlib import pyplot
import h5py
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard
from numpy import *

from hyperas import optim
from hyperas.distributions import choice, uniform
from hyperopt import Trials, STATUS_OK, tpe
from configuration.data_loader import *

def data():

    # normalise features
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

    X_train_df , y_train_df , X_val_df , y_val_df , X_test_df , y_test_df  = load_saved_datasets()

    X_train_df =  scaler.fit_transform(X_train_df.get_values())
    X_val_df =  scaler.fit_transform(X_val_df.get_values())

    y_train_df = y_train_df.get_values()
    y_val_df = y_val_df.get_values()

    X_train = X_train_df
    y_train = y_train_df
    X_val = X_val_df
    y_val = y_val_df

    return (X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val)


def model(X_train, y_train, X_val, y_val):
    """

    :param X_train: SCALED
    :param y_train:
    :param X_val: SCALED
    :param y_val:
    :return:
    """

    X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
    X_val = X_val.reshape((X_val.shape[0], 1, X_val.shape[1]))


    model = Sequential()

    # Layer 1
    model.add(LSTM({{uniform(4,70)}},
                    input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
    model.add(Activation({{choice(['tanh', 'relu'])}}))
    model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))

    # If we choose 'four', add an additional fourth layer
    if {{choice(['two', 'three'])}} == 'two':
        # Layer 2
        model.add(LSTM({{uniform(4,100)}},
                       input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
        model.add(Activation({{choice(['tanh', 'relu'])}}))
        model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))


    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Activation({{choice(['softmax', 'relu', 'tanh'])}}))

    model.compile(loss='rmse', metrics=['accuracy'],
                  optimizer={{choice(['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd'])}})

    result = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
                       batch_size={{choice([64, 128])}},
                       epochs=2,
                       verbose=2,
                       validation_data=(X_val, y_val))

    #get the highest validation accuracy of the training epochs
    validation_acc = amax(result.history['val_acc'])
    print('Best validation acc of epoch:', validation_acc)
    return {'loss': -validation_acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}

def hyperas_main():

    trials = Trials()
    best_run, best_model = optim.minimize(data=data,
                                        model=model,
                                          algo=tpe.suggest,
                                          max_evals=20,
                                          trials=trials)

    X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test = data()
    print("Evaluation of best performing model:")
    print(best_model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test))
    print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    print(best_run)

    # print("Evalutation of best performing model:")
    # # print(best_model.evaluate(X_val, y_val))
    # print("Best performing model chosen hyper-parameters:")
    # print(best_run)
```

Where the function load_saved_datasets() simply loads my sets with pandas.

However, the error output looks as follows:

```
   >>> Hyperas search space:

def get_space():
    return {
        'LSTM': hp.uniform('LSTM', 4,70),
        'Activation': hp.choice('Activation', ['tanh', 'relu']),
        'Dropout': hp.uniform('Dropout', 0, 1),
        'Dropout_1': hp.choice('Dropout_1', ['two', 'three']),
        'LSTM_1': hp.uniform('LSTM_1', 4,100),
        'Activation_1': hp.choice('Activation_1', ['tanh', 'relu']),
        'Dropout_2': hp.uniform('Dropout_2', 0, 1),
        'Activation_2': hp.choice('Activation_2', ['softmax', 'relu', 'tanh']),
        'optimizer': hp.choice('optimizer', ['rmsprop', 'adam', 'sgd']),
        'batch_size': hp.choice('batch_size', [64, 128]),
    }

>>> Data
  1: 
  2: 
  3: # normalise features
  4: scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
  5: 
  6: X_train_df , y_train_df , X_val_df , y_val_df , X_test_df , y_test_df  = load_saved_datasets()
  7: 
  8: X_train_df =  scaler.fit_transform(X_train_df.get_values())
  9: X_val_df =  scaler.fit_transform(X_val_df.get_values())
 10: 
 11: y_train_df = y_train_df.get_values()
 12: y_val_df = y_val_df.get_values()
 13: 
 14: X_train = X_train_df
 15: y_train = y_train_df
 16: X_val = X_val_df
 17: y_val = y_val_df
 18: 
 19: 
 20: 
 21: 
>>> Resulting replaced keras model:

   1: def keras_fmin_fnct(space):
   2: 
   3:     """
   4: 
   5:     :param X_train: SCALED
   6:     :param y_train:
   7:     :param X_val: SCALED
   8:     :param y_val:
   9:     :return:
  10:     """
  11: 
  12:     X_train = X_train.reshape((X_train.shape[0], 1, X_train.shape[1]))
  13:     X_val = X_val.reshape((X_val.shape[0], 1, X_val.shape[1]))
  14: 
  15: 
  16:     model = Sequential()
  17: 
  18:     # Layer 1
  19:     model.add(LSTM(space['LSTM'],
  20:                     input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
  21:     model.add(Activation(space['Activation']))
  22:     model.add(Dropout(space['Dropout']))
  23: 
  24:     # If we choose 'four', add an additional fourth layer
  25:     if space['Dropout_1'] == 'two':
  26:         # Layer 2
  27:         model.add(LSTM(space['LSTM_1'],
  28:                        input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
  29:         model.add(Activation(space['Activation_1']))
  30:         model.add(Dropout(space['Dropout_2']))
  31: 
  32: 
  33:     model.add(Dense(1))
  34:     model.add(Activation(space['Activation_2']))
  35: 
  36:     model.compile(loss='rmse', metrics=['accuracy'],
  37:                   optimizer=space['optimizer'])
  38: 
  39:     result = model.fit(X_train, y_train,
  40:                        batch_size=space['batch_size'],
  41:                        epochs=2,
  42:                        verbose=2,
  43:                        validation_data=(X_val, y_val))
  44: 
  45:     #get the highest validation accuracy of the training epochs
  46:     validation_acc = amax(result.history['val_acc'])
  47:     print('Best validation acc of epoch:', validation_acc)
  48:     return {'loss': -validation_acc, 'status': STATUS_OK, 'model': model}
  49: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/AI/Backend/src/main.py", line 40, in <module>
    lstm_training.hyperas_main()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\AI\Backend\src\training\lstm_training.py", line 94, in hyperas_main
    trials=trials)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py", line 67, in minimize
    verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperas\optim.py", line 133, in base_minimizer
    return_argmin=True),
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 307, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin,
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 635, in fmin
    return_argmin=return_argmin)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 320, in fmin
    rval.exhaust()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 199, in exhaust
    self.run(self.max_evals - n_done, block_until_done=self.async)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 173, in run
    self.serial_evaluate()
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\fmin.py", line 92, in serial_evaluate
    result = self.domain.evaluate(spec, ctrl)
  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\AI\lib\site-packages\hyperopt\base.py", line 840, in evaluate
    rval = self.fn(pyll_rval)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\AI\Backend\src\temp_model.py", line 110, in keras_fmin_fnct
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'X_train' referenced before assignment
```

Where do I reference X_train before use? Is this due to naming conventions? Does the problem lie maybe with a computational graph?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your two reshape() statements at the end of the data() function instead of in the model() function, and in the hyperas_main() function, define data() before you run optim.minimize().